# ASP.Net: Using UpdatePanels in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to build a sort of Accordion effect using a GridView and UpdatePanels. And I have problems with tieing everything together:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridMain" 
    runat="server" 
    ...  
 >

 <Columns>

 ...

 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
 <ItemTemplate> 

 <span>Id:<%# Eval("Id") %></span>

 <a href="/* javascript code to open the updatepanel??*/" title="Open"><img ..../></a>

 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="false">

 <asp:Label Text="??"/>

 </asp:PlaceHolder>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>


 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 </Columns>

 </asp:GridView>
```

How do I open the update panel using javascript?

Comment: I've never tried having UpdatePanel in a Data Control, not even sure if it'll work. You might want to try JQuery for the accordion effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to go with the UpdatePanel approach, here's how to make it work:

1. Specify IDs for the UpdatePanel and PlaceHolder controls
2. Put a LinkButton inside the UpdatePanel and get rid of the link you currently have
3. In the GridView's ItemCommand, use FindControl to get a reference to the PlaceHolder control and make it visible. You could also use a Repeater instead of a GridView here.

Now I would also say this is probably not the best idea... but hammers, nails, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For an accordion effect maybe [this website](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx) will help.  AJAX handles it quite nicely.

Comment: I need it to be in a GridView though. The panel must also be loaded dynimcally and be updatable during the page visit.

Comment: @Niels Using JQuery Ajax functions can do that as well.